# How to assign a postgres query to a variable in node.js, Discord bot and postgres integration?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, npm, discord, discord.js

Me and my friend have started talking about a business venture.
We decided on using Discord as the platform.
I am a novice coder and know a bit about: Discord.js, Java, HTML.

### Here’s the process:

- We have a website where a subscription could be bought.
- Once the subscription is purchased we want a code to be generated.
- And use that code to verify the person who bought the subscription.
- The generated code will allow the person to enter the server.
- The generated code will have to be read by the Discord.js bot and assign a role.

Any suggestions on where to start or what to do will be great.
If needed I will provide some of the code and things I have thought of using. Trying to find a way to generate a code and integrate it in Discord.js and HTML is what I am struggling with.

(Edited after this...)

So I have started doing this and came across 2 problems.

```js
bot.on('message', async message => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (message.channel.id === "*********************") {
    if (message.content === "/clear") return;
    let MessageContent = message.content;
    client.query(`SELECT * FROM public."GeneratedCodes" WHERE generated_codes = '${MessageContent}'`)
      .then(results => {
        if (MessageContent === results.rows) {
          let msg = message.reply(`***Code worked!*** ${results.rows}`)
          msg.then(message => {
            message.delete({
              timeout: 3000
            })
          })
        } else {
          let msg = message.reply("Code ***DIDN'T*** work :(")
          msg.then(message => {
            message.delete({
              timeout: 3000
            })
          })
        }
      })
      .catch(e => console.log(e))
  }
});
```

So I want to make a query (I have already setup the postgresql) where the query must find a value equal to `message.content`, But I can't compare `message.content` to `results.rows`, how could I store `client.query(SELECT * FROM public."GeneratedCodes" WHERE generated_codes = '${MessageContent}')` into a variable that could be compared to another variable?

Comment: Hey there, StackOverflow is not always the best place to ask questions like "How do I start doing this project". Generally there are 100's of answers of how to implement something, and being a programmer is knowing how to implement them. You're unlikely to get a great answer to this question because it's broad and open ended. The best questions for StackOverflow are those that have code and are generally issues or problems implementing a certain feature. I know it isn't the answer you're looking for but hopefully this gives you some insight if the question goes unanswered

Comment: When you said `Discord.js, Java, HTML` do you mean `Javascript` or just `Java`?

Comment: Since I'm already here it's worth throwing my hat in the ring. For the website you have tons of different sources to help you. codecademy is great for learning static site development, and you have frameworks like django and flask (python) if you're looking for something full stack. Python is similar to JS and may be easy to work in if you lack experience. You could also write your discord bot in python, and there are tons of guides out there with a quick google search. This way your entire platform is in one language, and will require less setup time to get going.

Comment: @Pepe_Worm I meant Java but I do Know a bit of Javascript aswell.

Comment: Well Java and JavaScript are two different things. Correct me if I'm wrong here, but I'm pretty sure that code above is written in JavaScript. Also, looked at babbitt's comment and yes, you could learn Python for the backend but you can also learn Node.js and Express so you wouldn't really have to learn a new language. Either works though

Comment: @Pepe_Worm So I meant Java in the context of the question, I coded the bot in JavaScript, sorry if it is confusing :3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## **Ok so this was one hell of a ride, but I figured it out...**

Just a side-note, for you reading this answer... This is tricky so watch the videos and ask if you need help.

### So here is the answer step by step:

**1. Firstly you need to set up a Postgres database, use the link below:**

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KH4OsSCZJUo&t

**2. Secondly, I needed to import randomly generated codes using a .csv file,
Using the website linked below:**

> https://www.randomcodegenerator.com/en/home

It's easier importing a .csv file to Postgres. Using the following video to do so:

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KTcEg35Xd38

**3. Once you have the Postgres database setup do the following:**

-Start by watching this video on how to use the `npm install pg` library and how to connect your node.js to your Postgres database:

> https://youtu.be/ufdHsFClAk0

**After which you can use this code to guide you through the discord `message.content` to authenticate that the code inserted is valid in the database:**

```
    bot.on('message', async message => {
    let EmbedCodeMessageInvalid = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor("#00A9B7")
      .setTitle("Verification Code:")
      .setDescription(`${message.author.username}, your code is INVALID | :)`)
      .setFooter(`VirtualKicksBot | Virtualkick.co.za`, "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0269/8146/6177/files/Mooi_large.jpg");
      let EmbedCodeMessageValid = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor("#00A9B7")
      .setTitle("Verification Code:")
      .setDescription(`${message.author.username}, your code is VALID. Welcome to the channel | :)`)
      .setFooter(`VirtualKicksBot | Virtualkick.co.za`, "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0269/8146/6177/files/Mooi_large.jpg");
    if(message.author.bot) return;
    if(message.channel.id === "**********************"){
    if(message.content === "/clear") return;
    let MessageContent = message.content;
    await client.query(`SELECT * FROM public."GeneratedCodes" WHERE generated_codes = $1`, [`${MessageContent}`])
    .then(results => {
      let CodeMessage = JSON.stringify(results.rows);
      let SubCodedMessage = CodeMessage.substring(21, 31)
      if(MessageContent === SubCodedMessage){
       let msg = message.reply({ embed: EmbedCodeMessageValid })
       msg.then(message => {
         message.delete({timeout: 5000});
       })
       message.delete({timeout: 5000});
      message.guild.members.cache.get(message.author.id).roles.add("713016390998687766");
      }else{
        let msg = message.reply({ embed: EmbedCodeMessageInvalid });
        msg.then(message => {
          message.delete({timeout: 5000})
        })
        message.delete({timeout: 5000})
      }
    })
    .catch(e => console.log(e))
  }
  });
```

**4. I'll go through the code segment by segment:**

**~The first line is `bot.on('message' => async message {}) :**

What this does is it calls the discord bot when a message is sent in the server.

**~The lines from 2 - 11 are embeds that were created to make the message that the bot sends back look a bit better (If you guys want me to give an in-depth tutorial on how to do this, please comment and I'll do it).**

**~From line 12 - 14 are if statements that set a criterium so that is it is met or net the code will run or not:**

-First if: `if(message.author.bot) return;` If the message is sent by a bot the program won't run.

-Second if: `if(message.channel.id === "720993727811813406")` if you want the bot only to run this code in a specific channel.

-Third if: `if(message.content === "/clear") return;` If you have a bulk delete or other command it won't run the code if the message has the command in the message.

**~Line 15 `let MessageContent = message.content;` stores the message sent in the server into a variable tho be used later.**

**~Line 16 `await client.query(SELECT * FROM public."GeneratedCodes" WHERE generated_codes = $1, [${MessageContent}])` this is where your query is made. Note that we want to see if the message content is in the database.   IF you get confused go watch the video on how to use `Postgres node.js integration` video which was listed above.**

**~Lines 17 - 34:**

=> So what happens in this segment is as follows: 
The `.then(results = {CODE_IN_HERE})`, returns a promise and `results` is the variable that is used to return the `client.query` so when you `console.log(results.rows)` it will return as follows: `({COULOMB_NAME: 'QUERY_RESULT'})`.

So what you should do to be able to read and compare the `query result` is to make a variable and `JSON.stringify(VARIABLE_X)` and `let VARIABLE_X_SUB = VARIABLE_X.substring(begin value, end value)`, this allows you to compare `MessageContent (Which is message.content)` to the `query result`.

**4. After you have compared the `query result` to the `MessageContent` using an IF statement you could do what you want with the bot like sending those `Embeds` to the channel or giving roles to users.**

## If you have any questions please ask and I will try and make a video to better explain this!